# haystack 2 SearchQuerySet with filter by list matching with exact string

Tags: solr, filter, django-haystack, searchqueryset

How can I filter by string list in haystack 2.0?

In Haystack 1.2 with Solr, if I have this code:

```
result = SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel).filter(my_field__in=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Result will exactly return objects with my_field equals to 'A', 'B' or 'C'. Instead, in Haystack 2.0 with Solr we will obtain objects with my_field as 'A', 'A something', 'B', 'B something'. I need preserve the haystack 1.2 behavior. Any idea?

If I use in Haystack 2.0:

```
result = SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel).filter(my_field=Exact('A'))
```

I will obtain objects with my_field equals to 'A'. Good! But I do not find one solution for filter with exact values in a list.

I need your help. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution. In **Haystack 2.0**, the schema.xml generated for solr has the next definition related to default text field:

```
   <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
          <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
          <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

In **Haystack 1.2**, the schema.xml generated for solr has this other definition:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

If you compare the analyzers in both definitions you can check that **Haystack 1.2** version  use **solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory**, and **Haystack 2.0** version use **solr.StandardTokenizerFactory**.

To keep the behavior of Haystack 1.2 in Haystack 2.0 you can create new text field type named, for example, "text_exact" with the same content of text field definition of Haystack 1.2 and then you associate all text fields in schema.xml with "text_en" to "text_exact".

From this version:

```
<field name="sales_user" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

We will obtain this other version:

```
<field name="sales_user" type="text_exact" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

The Haystack 2.0 official documentation does not provide a solution to this big change. It would be interesting to include some examples like this in section dedicated to migration from Haystack 1.x to 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Haystack 2.4.1.
I faced similar problem. The reason is that the field should not be analyzed.

To make the index of field 'not_analyzed' pass **indexed** parameter as False.
So while indexing the field I have used the following parameters.

```
    field_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='db_field',indexed=False)
```

So that field_name will become 'not_analyzed'

After that you apply your query.